# Solving a System of Vector Equations

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, normed-spaces

I'm trying to solve a system of vector equations, but I have no idea how to do it.  The following is a basic example of what I'm trying to solve:

$p = a*x + b*y$

$x = (p - y).normalize() + z$

where p, x, y, and z are 3D vectors.

I want to be able to solve this without making it a system of six equations by writing out how to evaluate the normalize function.  I'm fine with solving three pairs of a system of two equations (one for each component of the vector) as long as I can solve the system of two equations once for one component and then input the corresponding values for the other two components.

## My Original Problem

I want to take the formula for the force of a spring ($F_k = -kx$) and combine it wither Newton's second law ($F = ma$) and the kinematic formula ($p_{new} = p_{old} + v_{old} * t + \frac{1}{2} at^2$) to get a formula for the positions for two masses connected by a spring after a certain amount of time given their start positions and velocities.

$p = p_o + v_o * t + \frac{at^2}{2}$ (kinematic formula for the first end of the spring)

$q = q_o + w_o * t + \frac{a_2t^2}{2}$ (kinematic formula for the second end of the spring)

The force on both ends of the springs are equal opposites, so

$a = F_k / m$ where m is the mass of the first end

$a_2 = - F_k / n$ where n is the mass of the second end

Then you can replace $a$ and $a_2$ with their values in the first two equations:

$p = p_o + v_o * t + \frac{F_kt^2}{2m}$

$q = q_o + w_o * t - \frac{F_kt^2}{2n}$

Using Hooke's law, we can calculate the force

$F_k = -kx$

$p = p_o + v_o * t - \frac{kxt^2}{2m}$

$q = q_o + w_o * t + \frac{kx_2t^2}{2n}$

$x$ is the distance vector between the mass and the equilibrium of the spring.  For example, if the spring at rest has a length of 10, then $x$ would be the distance vector between the end of the spring and 10 length units from the other end.  In other words, $x$ is the distance between the ends of the spring minus the normal length of the spring (10)

$x = (p - q) - l$

However, $(p - q)$ is a vector, and $l$ is a scalar.  The direction of $l$ should be the same as $(p - q)$.  Therefore, the equation should be

$x = (p - q) - (p - q).normalize() * l$

Actually, this is the $x$ for the first end of the spring (since $p - q$ points toward the second end).  However, the $x$ for the other end will just be $-x_1$

So we get

### Final System of Equations

$p = p_o + v_o * t - \frac{kxt^2}{2m}$

$q = q_o + w_o * t - \frac{kxt^2}{2n}$ I replaced $x_2$ with $-x$

$x = (p - 1) - (p - q).normalize() * l$

(PS. Please tell me if I made any errors forming this.  I seem to come up with something slightly different each time.  So I may have made a mistake)

Comment: $x$ is clearly a multiple of $p$, so if nonzero they are parallel. If $y$ is also nonzero and _not_ parallel to $x$, then $b$ must be zero.

Comment: @amid interesting, but that unfortunately won't help with my original problem.  I'll change $x = p.normalize()$ to $x = p.normalize + z$ so that $x$ and $p$ don't have to be parallel.

Comment: Perhaps you might provide a description of the problem that you’re actually trying to solve for context instead of introducing more mysterious unexplained variables into your question.

Comment: @amid alright, I'll do that.